# Восстановление объектов в C#

Tags: c#

В своей книге Троелсен пишет:

> ...детали, касающиеся сборки мусора (вроде слабых ссылок и
>   восстановления объектов), остались не рассмотренными...

Где бы можно в доступно виде прочитать про это? Гуглил "Object resurrection", но ничего хорошего на русском вообще не нашел.

Comment: Да там писать то не о чем, почти. Точно есть упоминание об этом в "C# 5.0 in a Nutshell". Эта книга должна быть на русском

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ну, раз не нашли, давайте я расскажу.

Объекты делятся на те, которым нужна финализация (то есть, те, у которых есть *деструктор*-*финализатор*), и те, которые обходятся без неё. Вторых объектов гораздо больше: обычно вам не нужен деструктор в объекте. Такие объекты нам не интересны, пропускаем их.

Итак, что происходит во время пробега сборщика мусора? Он находит все объекты, на которые нету корневых ссылок (возможно, косвенных) и ссылок из «живых» локальных переменных. Эти объекты помещаются в список на уничтожение.

Теперь, те из них, которым нужна финализация¹, перемещаются в отдельную очередь для финализации. Остальные объекты просто уничтожаются².

Заметьте, что очередь финализации является корневым объектом, поэтому элементы, которые уже там лежат, не являются кандидатами на удаление.

Отдельный поток³ следит за очередью финализации, и понемногу финализирует объекты оттуда. Это значит, что у этих объектов вызывается финализатор. После этого объект удаляется из очереди, и таким образом подлежит *повторной* сборке мусора. Больше очередь финализации не ссылается на объект, и он в принципе должен быть собран сборщиком мусора при следующем пробеге.

Однако, финализатор — это такая же функция⁴. И эта функция может сделать что-то, что сделает объект недоступным для сборщика мусора! Например, поместит ссылку на этот объект в глобальную переменную.

Таким образом, у нас получается воскресший объект, который к тому же уже профинализирован! CLR запоминает, что объект уже был финализирован, и больше не будет пытаться его финализировать снова. (Вы можете сбросить этот флаг при помощи `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize`, устроив потенциально бесконечный цикл.)

Заметьте, что даже если вы полностью контролируете код своего объекта, вы не можете предотвратить «оживление» вашего объекта другим объектом! Смотрите: если другой финализируемый объект содержит ссылку на ваш, и они оба попадают в очередь финализации, и этот самый другой объект в результате финализации оживает, то он «тянет за собой» с того света назад на этот все объекты, доступные по его ссылкам! В частности, и ваш объект.

Несмотря на то, что восстановление объектов, пойманных сборщиком мусора, возможно, эта техника очень сложная, опасная и практически на грани фола. Поэтому я бы предостерёг от её использования для целей, отличных от простого развлечения. Если вам захотелось оживить объект, возможно, вам просто нужен явно управляемый пул объектов?

PS: Учитывая сложности корректной финализации, стоит просто избегать её по возможности. Если вы используете финализатор для работы с неуправляемыми ресурсами, то достаточно вместо `IntPtr` использовать `SafeHandle`, и необходимость в финализации отпадёт.

Обратите внимание, что не стоит доверять финализатору ещё и по такой причине: функции `GC.SuppressFinalize()` и `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize()` для *вашего* объекта может вызвать *любой* код!

---

¹ Вы можете, однако, запретить финализацию даже для объекта с финализатором при помощи метода `GC.SuppressFinalize`. Это полезно, например, если вы имплементируете `IDisposable`, и в методе `Dispose` подчищаете все ресурсы.

² Если только на них нету ссылок из объектов, помещаемых в очередь для финализации, т. к. эти объекты после помещения в очередь снова имеют корневую ссылку!

³ В текущей реализации подсистемы сборки мусора, разумеется.

⁴ С некоторыми предосторожностями: в финализаторе нужно с осторожностью работать, например, с управляемыми полями, потому что их содержимое может быть уже финализировано!

Comment: Зачем это может понадобится? Как я понимаю после финализации объект не содержит данных. Не проще ли создать новый экземпляр?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Вопрос не в том, зачем это может понадобиться. (И ответ: это не нужно практически никогда, не делайте этого.) Вопрос здесь в том, что язык не может _запретить_ финализатору прописать корневую ссылку на объект, и превратить тем самым объект в неподлежащий сборке мусора. А значит, язык _обязан_ делать всё так, как описано, иначе по ссылке будет чужая память!

Comment: Что-то вторая сноска подозрительная. Уверен?

Comment: @iluxa1810, неверно. Что значит "после финализации"? Ты сам управляешь финализацией и тем, что будет содержать объект после неё. Да, managed-объекты могут стать мусором сами, но всем остальным ты управляешь. Зачем надо? В некоторых случаях этот трюк позволяет повысить производительность. Но использовать надо крайне осторожно. И да, ещё из особенностей - не гарантируется, что финализатор вообще вызовется.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде бы [да](https://nabacg.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/what-do-you-know-about-freachable-queue/), но сейчас уточню.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вот [пруф](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/20/77460.aspx): _People sometimes incorrectly assume that this is because those other objects have already been collected.  Yet, as I have explained, the entire reachable graph from a finalizable object is promoted. // The real reason for the guideline is to avoid touching objects that may have already been finalized.  That’s because finalization is unordered._

Answer (score 11):

На русском:

- [Источники о сборке мусора в .NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/10/net.html)
- [Немного о сборке мусора и поколениях](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/10/blog-post.html)
- [Слабые ссылки в .NET](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/08/net.html)
- [О сборке мусора и достижимости объектов](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/08/blog-post_27.html)

На английском:

- [When everything you know is wrong, part one](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/)
- [When everything you know is wrong, part two](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)

Очень советую посмотреть статьи Эрика Липперта - там очень хорошо показывается, что всегда может что-то быть не так, как ты ожидаешь.

Comment: Последние две ссылки особенно хороши.

Comment: @VladD, согласен - хороши. Да и вообще, хороший блог. Но перевод есть только для старого блога (который на msdn), да и то не для всего.

Comment: Хотя и у Сергея хорошо, но не настолько концентрировано по теме.

Comment: @VladD, просто в данном случае посты Эрика больше соответствуют вопросу. В общем-то, у них обоих было ещё что-то про сборку мусора, но ищется что-то не очень.