# Почему поток выходит из деструктора, содержащего бесконечный цикл

Tags: c#

Почему приложение завершает свою работу? Ведь в деструкторе должно быть зацикливание:

```
namespace Core
{
    class Test
    {
        ~Test() { while (true); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Потому что в C# деструктор (а точнее, финализатор, так он называется) работает по-другому. Он вызывается не сразу, а когда-нибудь потом, да и то лишь при условии, что сборщик мусора удалит объект. Поскольку запуск сборщика мусора не гарантирован, то и вызов вашего финализатора тоже не гарантирован.

Кроме того, финализаторы бегут в отдельном потоке, а если в конце работы приложения финализация бежит слишком долго, то она насильно обрывается.

В вашем случае программа короткая и не нагружает память, понятно, что сборщик мусора запущен скорее всего не будет.

---

Для нужной вам семантики гарантированного вызова метода для уничтожения объекта вам нужно реализовать интерфейс `IDisposable` и воспользоваться конструкцией `using`.

```
class Test : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { while (true) ; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Test test = new Test())
        { }
    }
}
```

---

Дополнительная информация по теме:

- [Как и когда нужно имплементировать IDisposable?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/486696/10105)
- [Восстановление объектов в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432478/10105)
- [When everything you know is wrong, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) и [part two](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/)

Comment: поток обрубается так и не вызвав деструктор.

Comment: @StanislavPetrov: Скорее всего просто до финализации и не доходит.

Comment: Ссылочку на What you know is wrong добавь ;)

Comment: @StanislavPetrov, нет, думаю, в данном случае он вызывается, но через некоторое время прерывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, как раз был в процессе добавления :)

Comment: У меня на тестах на компе деструктор вызывается, но обрывается. Как раз из-за "если в конце работы приложения финализация бежит слишком долго, то она насильно обрывается". Думаю, именно этот кусок и есть истинно правильным ответом на сам вопрос, ведь GC при этом НЕ вызывается, что можно явно увидеть в окне Diagnostic tools по графику. (если добавить до и после Thread.Sleep(1000); )

Comment: @Andrew https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/ && https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/

Comment: @Andrew: Объект помещается в очередь для финализации именно сборщиком мусора. Так что вам повезло, сборщик мусора увидел ваш объект.

Comment: @VladD, а почему мог не увидеть-то? Ну кроме превышения этого самого лимита?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Например, рантайм мог решить вообще не запускать сборщик мусора, зачем, приложение-то завершается?.

Comment: @Andrew: Возможно, диагностическое окно показывает лишь полную сборку, а не Gen0.

Comment: @VladD, а вдруг там глобальные для системы семафоры? Как-то без причины финализаторы пропускать было бы сранно. Хотя [FailFast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100(v=vs.110).aspx) тоже никто не отменял :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, *гарантии* финализации нет, так что надеяться на это для очистки глобальных объектов тоже не стоит.

Comment: @Qwertiy для таких случаев есть CriticalFinalizerObject