# Вызов виртуальных методов из обычных методов

Tags: c#, .net

В C# есть весьма странное и опасное разрешение- это вызов виртуальных методов внутри обычных методов.

Например, можно сделать, что бы конструктор базового класса вызывал внутри себя виртуальный метод, а тот в свою очередь может быть переопределен в наследнике, что может привести к непредсказуемым результатам.

В каких случаях- это может понадобится? Мне кажется, что больше -, чем +.

Рихтер, вроде, тоже не рекомендует так делать.

Comment: чем оно странно и опасно? _что может привести к непредсказуемым результатам._ - этак про **любой** код можно сказать

Comment: Про непредсказуемые результаты не понял. Пока вижу только одну проблему - вызываемый в конструкторе метод может обратиться к еще не инициализированному полю экземпляра, но это касается любых методов - не имеет значения, виртуальные они или нет. И да, так делать не надо.

Comment: Вопрос я думаю в первую очередь про конструктор и вызов в нём виртуальных функций. Там вроде есть какие то подводные камни потенциально. Как минимум - вызов функции у недостроенного класса.

Comment: @Monk, да, наверное мне нужно было переформулировать под конструктор.

Comment: У виртуальных методов всегда есть реализация, просто ее можно переопределить, реализации нет только у абстрактных методов, абстрактные методы только в абстрактных классах, но у абстрактных классов вы не можете вызвать конструктор. Так что не понятно, что подразумевается под вызовом функции у недостроенного класса. Единственная сложность, что не всегда понятно, в каком классе используется функция родителя, а в каком она была переопределена, это приходится держать в голове

Comment: @B.Vandyshev почитайте, да и автору пригодится - https://stackoverflow.com/a/119543/3768545

Comment: Понял вас, действительно, так и есть, забавно никогда не использовал виртуальные методы в конструкторе. Дополню свой ответ

Answer (score 3):

> В каких случаях- это может понадобится?

Вызов виртуального метода в конструкторе нужен, как обычно, когда в методе нужна логика, зависящая от конкретного производного класса.

Пример:

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        var animalName = GetName();
        Console.WriteLine($"New {animalName} is born!");
    }
    protected virtual string GetName() => "Generic animal";
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    protected override string GetName() => "Cat";
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override string GetName() => "Dog";
}
```

Аналогичный код в C++ вывел бы `"New Generic animal is born!"` для любого животного, что явно не является интуитивно ожидаемым поведением.

---

Известная проблема, конечно, заключается в том, что объект может быть не полностью инициализирован к моменту вызова виртуального метода, поэтому вызов в принципе может завершиться ошибкой. Но это часть более общей проблемы: ведь вызов и невиртуального метода в конструкторе может завершиться с ошибкой, т. к. этот метод прямо или косвенно может предполагать полную инициализацию объекта.

Запретить вызывать виртуальные методы из конструктора, как мы видим, не поможет избежать проблемы. Запретить вызывать виртуальные методы из невиртуальных — слишком сильное ограничение: если это будет так, мы не сможем выносить общую логику в отдельные, невиртуальные методы. Запретить вызов любых методов из конструктора кажется слишком сильным запретом.

Поэтому решение проблемы — внимательно следить за тем, какие именно предусловия накладывают методы на вызывающий код.

Comment: **Аналогичный код в C++ вывел бы "New Generic animal is born!" для любого животного, что явно не является интуитивно ожидаемым поведением.** оно неожиданно только для тех, кто не знает с++. Для всех остальных абсолютно ожидаемое.

Comment: @KoVadim: Неожиданность хорошо видна в том, что программистам на C++ приходится его специально учить эту странность языка. А для программистов на C# код работает интуитивно понятно, так что вопросов не возникает. (Ну и да, я _кое-как_ знаю C++. Но для меня это поведение всё ещё не интуитивно ожидаемое.)

Comment: ага, ответ выше как раз и показывает, как все прозрачно и интуитивно.

Comment: @KoVadim: Всё как раз прозрачно. Вызов метода до окончания инициализации объекта может привести к проблемам. Вне зависимости от того, это виртуальный метод или нет.

Comment: когда вызывается метод, который принадлежит объекту или его предкам, он может рассчитывать на то, базовая инициализация уже прошла. А вот методами наследников все сложнее... Их конструкторы к этому моменту ещё не отработали

Comment: @KoVadim: Разумеется. Но в любом случае механизм простой и прозрачный.

Comment: Вот из-за этой "прозрачности" и убрали эту "возможность". Деструкторы также убрали от греха подальше:)

Comment: @KoVadim: Это вы о каком языке? О C#? Какую возможность убрали?

Comment: @KoVadim: Насчёт «убрали деструкторы» вы троллите, или и правда не знаете?

Comment: тут хитрый троллинг:) я знаю что такая конструкция как деструктор в шарпе есть (в отличии от java). Вот только программист не может явно его вызвать. Поэтому и пишу "убрали (в смысле запихнули) подальше"

Comment: @KoVadim: Деструкторов в C# нету. Есть финализаторы. Нет, это вовсе не одно и то же.

Comment: то есть, то нет... уже определитесь. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors есть нечто, что выглядит как деструктор, крякает как деструктор, но деструктором как таковым не является

Comment: @KoVadim: Нет, крякает по-разному. Например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432478/10105

Answer (score -1):

По сути, виртуальные методы чем то схожи в методами в интерфейсах, вы знаете что такой метод будет и знаете его сигнатуру, и можете им воспользоваться, но при этом вы не знаете как он будет реализован внутри. Самое популярное использование - это метод `ToString()` во время разработки базового класса (в данной случае `object`) вы не можете знать как именно вам следует преобразовывать класс в строку, у вас есть какая то базовая реализация, в большинстве случаев она подходит, но вы хотите чтобы в дочерних классах эту логику можно было переопределить, но при этом в отличии от интерфейса, вы не хотите обязывать пользователя определять этот метод `ToString()` в каждом классе наследнике.

UPD: Так как речь о конструкторе, то тут могут возникать некоторые ньюансы
например код:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething() 
    {
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    private string foo;
    public Child() 
    { 
      foo = "HELLO";
    }

    protected override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToLower());
    }
}
```

В данном коде, метод `DoSomething()` будет вызван до конструктора `Client()` следовательно `foo` еще не будет проинициализирован и мы получим `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Кстати: https://ideone.com/CstCea. Это ещё один аргумент за inline-инициализацию полей.